# Prove that the sequence $\boldsymbol{x_1,x_2,x_3,}...$ converges in $\mathbb{R}^\omega_p$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In class we defined the Product Topology as so: 
$\mathbb{R}^{\omega} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times ...$

Box Topology: $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_b = \text{open set} \times \text{open set} \times ...$ 
Product Topology: $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p = \text{open set} \times ... \times \text{open set} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times ...$

Uniform Topology: $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_u$

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $\boldsymbol{x_1,x_2,x_3}$ be the sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, $\boldsymbol{x_i}=(x_{i,1},x_{i,2},...)$. Let $\pi_j$ be the $j$-th projection map from $\mathbb{R}^\omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
Prove that the sequence $\boldsymbol{x_1,x_2,x_3,}...$ converges in $\mathbb{R}^\omega_p$ if and only if for every $j$ the sequence $\pi_j(\boldsymbol{x_1}),\pi_j(\boldsymbol{x_2}),\pi_j(\boldsymbol{x_3}),...= x_{1,j},x_{2,j},x_{3,j},...$ converges.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ $(\implies)$ Given $\boldsymbol{x_i} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$, then by definition of convergent sequence, $\forall U \subset \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ where $U$ is open, $\boldsymbol{L} \in U$ and $\exists N$ with $\boldsymbol{x_i} \in U \,\, \forall i \geq N$.

We want to show $\boldsymbol{\pi_j} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$. So, we need to show $\exists N$ with $\boldsymbol{L} \in U$ such that $\boldsymbol{\pi_j} \in U \,\, \forall j \geq N$.

Let $U \subset  \mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$ be open. Since $U$ is open, then $V=U_1 \times U_2 \times ... \times U_t \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times ... \times \subset U$ with $\boldsymbol{L} \in V$.

So, $\boldsymbol{L}=(L_1,L_2,L_3,...,L_t,L_{t+1},...)$ where $L_1 \in U_1$, $L_2 \in U_2$,..., $L_t \in U_t$, $L_{t+1} \in \mathbb{R}$, ... because $\boldsymbol{L} \in V$.

Since $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \boldsymbol{x_i} \in U$, then $\forall j \,\, \pi_j \in U_i$ because $\pi_j=(x_{11}, x_{21}, x_{31},...),...$

$\therefore \forall j \,\, \pi_j(x_n) \in V \subset U$.

$\therefore \pi_j(x_n) \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$

$(\impliedby)$ Given $\boldsymbol{\pi_j} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$.
\
We want to show that $\boldsymbol{x_i} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$.

$\boldsymbol{\pi_j} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$ means $\forall \, \text{open} \,\, U \subset \mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$ with $\boldsymbol{L} \in U$, $\exists N$ such that $\boldsymbol{\pi_j} \in U \,\, \forall j \geq N$.

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$ be open. Since $U$ is open, then $V=U_1 \times U_2 \times ... \times U_t \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times ... \times \subset U$ where $U_i$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\boldsymbol{L} \in V \subset U$.

So, $\boldsymbol{L}=(L_1,L_2,L_3,...,L_t,L_{t+1},...)$ where $L_1 \in U_1$, $L_2 \in U_2$,..., $L_t \in U_t$, $L_{t+1} \in \mathbb{R}, ...$

Choose $N_1$ such that $\pi_1(\boldsymbol{x_n})=x_{n1} \in U_1 \,\, \forall n \geq N$, 
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$  $N_2$ such that $\pi_2(\boldsymbol{x_n}) \in U_2 \,\, \forall n \geq N$, ..., 
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$  $N_t$ such that $\pi_t(\boldsymbol{x_n}) \in U_t \,\, \forall n \geq N$, ..., 
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$  $N_{t+1}$ does not matter since $\pi_{t+1}(\boldsymbol{x_n}) \in \mathbb{R} \,\, \forall n \geq N$ and so on. 
Pick $N = \text{max}(N_1, ..., N_t)$. Then $\forall n \geq N$, $\pi_1(\boldsymbol{x_n}) \in U_1$, ..., $\pi_t(\boldsymbol{x_n}) \in U_t$, $\pi_{t+1}(\boldsymbol{x_n}) \in \mathbb{R}, ...$

So, $\boldsymbol{x_n} \in U_1 \times U_2 \times ... \times U_t \times U_{t+1} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times ... = V \subset U$ 
$\therefore \boldsymbol{x_n} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{L}$. $\,\, \blacksquare$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$?

Comment: In class, this is what we defined as the product topology as to differentiate it from the box topology and uniform topology.
I will define these topologies above.

Comment: Although I understand your definition, it isn’t written correctly (in particular it seems that $\mathbb R^\omega_p$ is a topological space, not a topology)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think that is something that confuses me. Does that mean $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ represents the Product Topology while $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}_p$ represents the Product Space?

Comment: $\mathbb R^\omega$ looks to be the underlying set. A topology is a set of subsets of the underlying set. A topological space is a pair $(X,\tau)$ where $X$ is a set and $\tau$ is a topology consisting of subsets of $X$.